What is the subject asking students to write about their understanding and appreciation for literary works?
When I was at school, we had a subject called "literary appreciation" if I translate its name directly into English. In this subject, we had to write about our understanding and appreciation for literary works, analyze them and point out why the authors wrote so and what was good about different details in those works.
Does such a subject/writing genre exist in English? What is it called?

We had to write a lot of essays expressing our understanding and appreciation for literary works.

As you can see, I had to say such a long sentence because I didn't know what genre of writing it was. I want to say:

We had to study literature appreciation and write essays about it.

or

We had to write a lot of literature appreciation essays.

but because there seems to be no such subject/writing genre in English, I'm not sure if these sentences are natural or well understood by native speakers.

Certainly it does. In my day it was called 'English Literature'.

I have the same question for you like the one I asked Jay. You are from two different countries, so it's great to know what it's like there.

In the US in elementary schools there is Music Appreciation but not Literature Appreciation. In high school, the reading and analysis of literary works occurs in "English class" or in  "English".  Who do you have for English? is a question one student might ask another, meaning "Who teaches the English class you're in?"

The appreciation of famous writers' works is still called 'English Literature' in the UK, as distinct from 'English Language' which covers grammar and the student's own creative writing.

This is a tricky one because this and similar subjects go by a lot of names. It can vary not only by region but by which level of study we're talking about.
One of the most common is simply "English." This might cause some confusion because if you enroll in "Spanish," it's a language course, but "English" is often a course in reading and analyzing "literature" and writing about it. For example, as a university major, an "English major" spends most of their time on the criticism and analysis of literature. "High school English" typically involves reading classics like Shakespeare or To Kill a Mockingbird and writing essays.
Such studies are often specialized, especially in higher education. When you narrow the field, the word "literature" is often used: "British Literature 101" (often casually shortened to "Brit Lit"), or "I majored in English with a concentration in Southern Gothic literature." It would not be surprising to find even a general survey course described as "Literature."
In recent years and especially in lower grades, I find the "reading and writing"-oriented courses described as "Language Arts." This reflects the fact that they're often placing equal emphasis on writing as well as reading. It also represents an "integrated" approach. In earlier days, some of these disciplines were taught separately. An old popular song summarizes the elementary curriculum as "Reading and writing and 'rithmetic." Along these lines, you still see "Composition" (meaning the craft of expressing yourself in writing) and "Penmanship" (meaning writing clearly by hand) taught as subjects independent from "Reading," especially in some traditionalist educational approaches.
To dig in a little deeper: There might not be a one-to-one translation because there might be a difference in the underlying philosophy. As a musician, I'm very familiar with the "appreciation" idea because a very common university course is "Music Appreciation" (and the similar "Art Appreciation" for visual arts). I've taught such a course and named mine "Music Enjoyment" instead, as I disagree with some of the assumptions about the arts that underlie the word. It comes from an aesthetic viewpoint that distinguishes between "Fine Arts" or "Great Music" as opposed to other artistic expressions. It assumes that the "un-fine art" and "un-great music"—that is, "popular" musics or artistic expressions—don't need to be studied, and that these more elevated works need assistance. It comes from the same sort of viewpoint that considers it a crisis that symphonies are becoming less popular. From this viewpoint, value is inherent in these works, and the problem is with the viewers or listeners who don't like them. The deficit must be that they simply don't "appreciate" this inherent value; they are either deficient in taste ("philistines") or simply unenlightened. So courses like these try to help you develop an "appreciation" for things that deserve to be "appreciated." (While my personal viewpoint is that study and broadening our exposure is great, and these so-called masterworks do in fact have a lot of value that isn't always easy to access, but the ultimate goal is not to "fix" deficient humans by "appreciating" the value of the art object, but to increase our enjoyment by experiencing something in a new way.)
So a "literature appreciation" course might assume that anyone can read bestselling paperbacks for fun, but that we need to be disciplined to "appreciate" "Great Literature." While this attitude might still inform the curriculum (there's a reason all the high schoolers are still reading Shakespeare and To Kill A Mockingbird), increasingly the field of literary criticism is moving away from a viewpoint that makes a polar distinction between what is "worth" reading and what is not, and instead focusing on teaching skills and themes and applying them to diverse sources.

We call it simply "literature". Like, "We studied literature and wrote essays about it."

So how do you distinguish it from other writing genres? We had four main types of writing: story-telling writing, descriptive writing (where you have to describe something), literary-appreciation writing, and social-matter writing. These are some literal translations so I guess they sound weird. We learn the first two in elementary school and the latter two in middle school and high school.

All these four are included in one subject - literature, but we often talked about each one of them separately.

In US schools, "literature" is generally understood to mean "classics". That is, books written many many years ago and that are remembered for being among the best. Generally limited to fiction stories. It includes a broad range of writing. Lite "Pilgrim's Progress", a book about what it means to be a Christian written as a fiction story, is considered "literature". So is "1984", a novel about a tyrannical government. Einstein's book "Relativity" would not be considered "literature" because it is non-fiction. ...

... But then, "Democracy in America" by Alexis de Tocqueville is sometimes considered literature even though it is non-fiction. So as to genres, there's no concrete list that everyone agrees on. In general we'd say there are fiction and non-fiction. Under non-fiction would be history, science, mathematics, travel, money, etc. Under fiction is mysteries, suspense, romance, general drama, science fiction, fantasy, war, and others. Any of these could be considered "literature" if written long enough ago and good enough.

I want to clear it up a bit. Only in literary appreciation writing did we learn about great writers' literary works. In the other three, we learned how to write each type of writing ourselves.

@AnIELTSLearner The categories you list, if I'm understanding what you mean correctly, are not categories normally used in American discussions of writing.

Oh I was writing my comment while you were writing yours. Let me read yours first.

@AnIELTSLearner When teaching writing, teachers will talk about "descriptions", "dialog", and "action". But we don't consider those categories of literature. You would routinely expect to find all three in the same story.
